# There is a way to order alphabetical in Gulp Sass?

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

My team hates a convention that we need to use. We need to export all css in alphabetical order, but we can work in our SCSS and we don't need to share it, so what its matters is css being orderded.

There is a way in gulp (we work with gulp-sass) to reorder when css is processed?

Note: I think alphabetical order is horrible even to readibility, its better to group by type (eg: box-model properties, text properties, ...)

Comment: _If_ such a (nonsense) convention is in use, then usually so that developers can find properties quicker in the source code that they are working with - that would be your _SASS_ in this case. What sense is it supposed to make to apply that to the output only?

Comment: Because there are two different complete steps: 1) we code in SASS; 2) They access our CSS. 1) We don't want to order alphabetical; 2) Its a convention to use. Its not a standart process, because basically we are working not for a specific project and same environment. So, the question is: can we order by type of property in SASS and get a final CSS orderer alphabetical?

Comment: Btw, alphabetical order is a famous convention in CSS. I totally disagree, but sometimes maybe we need to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

> [gulp-csscomb](https://github.com/koistya/gulp-csscomb)

Probably with this option after you have your css:

```
.pipe(csscomb({"sort-order-fallback": "abc"}))
```

See [sort-order configuration for csscomb](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/blob/dev/doc/options.md#sort-order-fallback)

Comment: Thanks! I need it to put options in css modules, and remove sort order. Need to test to do it in gulp file. {"sort-order-fallback": "abc",
    "sort-order": ["..."]}

Comment: We need to add a .csscomb.json file at root folder (or same level) to override default definitions. Its working. Thanks ;)